# Read-only file system like windows embedded FBWF

Tags: filesystem, read-only

I’d like to know if it’s possible to install ubuntu so that it acts like windows embedded FBWF (File Base Write Filter) so that once rebooted it will come back to its original state.

My intent is to build a system only for navigation purpose and all things user do during their sessions will be lost at next reboot unless they save their work on an extrnal drive.

Like a VM that every time is turned off restore its previous state.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EmbeddedUbuntu

Comment: Posting as a comment because I'm not certain, but I think logging in to a guest session does this. Reboot or log out and all the data is gone.

Comment: @TomBrossman For sure the user space’d get cleaned, but if the user took a rootkit the root space’d remain dirty. Instead I want the full (user/root) space to be read only

Comment: Since you include the possibility of a rootkit in your threat model, I believe only physically immutable media would meet your requirements. That means a Live CD written to DVD-R. @S_Flash's answer below looks good to me, as it includes customisation.

Comment: @TomBrossman I think that this solution https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/03/10/protecting-ubuntu-root-filesystem/ si the nearest to FBWF on windows. I will check this out.

Answer (score 1):

I think you search something like Ubuntu LiveCD. Take a look **LiveCDCustomization**: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization
In your case you need build and setup it to your filesystem and flag it readonly.

Comment: I’ll give it a try. But I don’t want to end up with a live cd but with an HD install.

Comment: Yes, CD - is just example of read-only FS. Change CD to HDD or SSD.

Comment: I think that this https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/03/10/protecting-ubuntu-root-filesystem/ is the nearest solution to what I've in mind. I will check this out.